# IE bug with global variables. How to bypass this bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

As title says i have some problems with IE8 and Javascript. It's known about its bug in interpretation of global variables: simply it does not get them if you don't declare as:

```
var variable1 = something;
```

The problem it's i'm trying to make a script that change the body background clicking on a button and i need a global variable wrapping the actual status (what bg-x.png i'm loading). This script work on FF, Safari and Chrome but not, obviously, on IE. Help? (the problem is on the variable "status")

```
$('#change').click(function() {
    var numStates = 2;
    var name = $(this).text();

    if(!(status)) {
        status = parseInt(1,10);
    }

    if(status<numStates) {
        status = parseInt(status,10) + 1;
    }
    else {
     status = parseInt(1,10);
    }


    alert(status);


    var bgvar = null;

    switch(parseInt(status,10)) {
        case 1: var bgvar = ' #7097ab url(./img/bg-' + status + '.png) top center repeat';
        var name = 'Pattern';
        break;
        case 2: var bgvar = ' #7097ab url(./img/bg-' + status + '.png) top center repeat-x';
        var name = 'Sfumato';
        break;
        default: alert('Default');
    }

    $('body').css({
        background:bgvar,
    });

    $(this).text(name);


}
);
```

Working code even with IE (Thanks to Zeta):

```
$('#change').click(function() {
   var numStates = 2;
   var name = $(this).text();

// If data-status isn't defined set it to the initial value
if($('body').data('status') === undefined)
    $('body').data('status',1);

// Extract the status
var status = parseInt($('body').data('status'),10);

// Handle the status
if(status < numStates)
    status++;
else
    status = 1;

// Save the status
$('body').data('status',status);




    switch(status) {
        case 1: bgvar = ' #7097ab url(./img/bg-' + status + '.png) top center repeat';
        name = 'Pattern';
        break;
        case 2: bgvar = ' #7097ab url(./img/bg-' + status + '.png) top center repeat-x';
        name = 'Sfumato';
        break;
        default: alert('Default');
    }

    $('body').css({
        background:bgvar,
    });

    $(this).text(name);


}
);
```

Comment: 1) Post the code containing the declaration of "status" and where is it declared. 2) Have you tried changing variable name? Maybe "status" is somehow a reserved IE8 keyword, don't know... Actually status is on this list of reserved JS keywords: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm

Comment: Global variables are *never* needed.

Comment: @cristy `status` is declared in that code block.

Comment: I found two erros in my code. The first about the variable name (that as Cristy suggests it's reserved) and one in checking if "status" was defined.
i'm editing with the correct code. 

Anyway @Lucero how can i avoid using global variable?

Comment: There are many ways to avoid them, Zeta has posted one of the solutions for that. The common way is to use a closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery you could use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead of global variables:

```
$('#change').click(function() {
    var numStates = 2;
    var name = $(this).text();

    // If data-status isn't defined set it to the initial value
    if($('body').data('status') === undefined)
        $('body').data('status',1);

    // Extract the status
    var status = parseInt($('body').data('status'),10);

    // Handle the status
    if(status < numStates)
        status++;
    else
        status = 1;

    // Save the status
    $('body').data('status',status);

    /* ... Rest of your code ... */
```

Note that this won't work in XML documents in IE (according to the jQuery doc).

Comment: I used your way. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

status is a predefined member of the window-object and points to the content of the statusbar. Use another variable-name

Answer (score 1):

Do you know when to use »var«?
I just cleaned your code in the follwing ways:

1. Add "var status;" to make it a local variable
2. Delete "var" for already defined variables in your switch statement
3. Delete the unnecessary comma behind "background: bgvar" which will cause errors in IE

   ```
   $('#change').click(function () {
           var numStates = 2;
           var name = $(this).text();
           var status;

           if (!(status)) {
                   status = parseInt(1, 10);
           }

           if (status < numStates) {
                   status = parseInt(status, 10) + 1;
           } else {
                   status = parseInt(1, 10);
           }


           alert(status);


           var bgvar = null;

           switch (parseInt(status, 10)) {
           case 1:
                   bgvar = ' #7097ab url(./img/bg-' + status + '.png) top center repeat';
                   name = 'Pattern';
                   break;
           case 2:
                   bgvar = ' #7097ab url(./img/bg-' + status + '.png) top center repeat-x';
                   name = 'Sfumato';
                   break;
           default:
                   alert('Default');
           }

           $('body').css({
                   background: bgvar
           });

           $(this).text(name);


   });
   ```

Does it work now?

P.S. Use http://www.jshint.com/ to prevent those kind of errors.

Comment: That's not going to work at all, because `status` is now going to be re-initialized on each call and therefore it loses the state is is supposed to carry along two calls.

Comment: It does not work because at the end of the function execution the status var is set back to 1. And i need it stays to the number increased during function execution. 

However thanks for your tips about use of "var". I'm not so expert with JS syntax as it is clear :)